# Since OpenGL can perform built in backface culling, it must calculate vertex normals; can these be accessed instead of sending them as attributes?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Would like to understand this; it’s not quite clear why you have to upload normals but at the same time respect the winding order for normal calculation.

Comment: because some normals for lighting are different (they are not perfectly perpendicular to face) than the result of the cross product of the face sides to simulate smooth surface ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All vertices you give OpenGL within a rendering command are in a specific order. For array rendering, this means the order of the vertices in the array, as specified by the drawing command. For indexed rendering, it's the order of the indices in the range of index values you're rendering from. Instanced rendering defines that the vertices for each instance happens after the previous instance's vertices. And so forth.

The [primitive assembly system for a triangle](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) takes this sequence of vertices and breaks it up into triangles, depend on which kind of primitive you rendered. This means that each vertex output by the primitive assembly system has an order relative to the others for that triange; one vertex came first, then another, then the third.

Since triangles only have 3 vertices, there are two ways for the rasterizer to look at this order. The vertices can either wrap clockwise around the triangle or counter-clockwise, as seen in screen space. This is the triangle's [winding order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Winding_Order): the apparent order of the vertices, as seen from screen space.

It is the winding order which is used to determine how face culling works, *not* the normal. The GPU never calculates vertex normals. Or normals of any kind.

Comment: "It is the winding order" a simple way to evaluate the winding normal is to take the cross product which implicitely calculates the normal. So I wouldn;t be surprised if some drivers use the crosss product for evaluation.

Comment: So it doesn’t use the winding order for cross products?

Comment: @Makogan: "*So I wouldn;t be surprised if some drivers use the crosss product for evaluation.*" Why? Why go through the trouble of taking a full vector cross product when all you're looking for is the Z axis of that product? And just the *sign* of that axis at that? So I would be very surprised if hardware bothered to compute a bunch of numbers that it will never use.

Comment: @MarkGreen: As I replied to Makogan, there's really no point in taking the cross product. The math for determining the winding order of a triangle is far less complex than the math needed for a cross product.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Why" because your hardware already has the specialized hardware to calculate normals and after benchmarking it turns out it's faster than the more efficient sfotware emulated version. For example.

Comment: @Makogan: "*because your hardware already has the specialized hardware to calculate normals*" Why would the *rasterizer* have specialized hardware to compute a face normal that the rasterizer would never be able to use? Individual shader cores may have specialized hardware for cross products (but don't count on it), but the rasterizer and/or primitive assembly unit isn't a shader core.

Comment: You seem too certain about an existential claim. A good reason as to why the GPU rasterizers would have it is because in hardware it's cheaper to reuse parts. So if you already have the circuits to calculate a cross product, it's cheaper to insert a couple of those in the rasterizer instead of creating specialized hardware that would e better / faster but more costly. Again, I didn't say "all" I said "some".

But at this point this is just cluttering the issue.

Comment: @Makogan: "*A good reason as to why the GPU rasterizers would have it is because in hardware it's cheaper to reuse parts.*" Microchips are not like physical objects. Broadly speaking, the cost of chip production is governed not by what your transistors are doing so much as the number of transistors and the interconnections between them. Copy-and-paste chip design saves you *nothing* in fabrication costs. And since the "code" for computing winding order has existed since long before GPUs had real computation units, it's better to copy-and-paste from your previous generation's rasterizer.

Comment: Basically, there's almost no reason why a GPU engineer would bother to use a more complicated process to compute the winding order unless they were actually performing the primitive assembly step using generic code fed to a compute unit. And that would only be done to allow for user-programmable primitive assembly, which is not a thing that exists at present.

Comment: I see the complexity difference in a first place instead of convenience of reusing modules: compute winding in 2D NDC is 1/3th of 3D cross product, using full cross product/normal in world or camera  coordinates needs full 3D cross computation + dot product or matrix multiplication to transform to NDC/screen space ...